# Automated WHM MySQL backup not working

Tags: backup, mysql

I am using WHM's automated backup system to make daily backups of my database.  I have it set that it only makes a backup of what has changed.  I've had this running for a while now and thought it was working fine until I tried downloading the backup today, and realized there was nothing in it.  The only text inside of the sql file is:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: pokerrpg_pokerrpg
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.81-community-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have WHM set to keep weekly or monthly backups as well?  Check the /pathtobackupfolder/cpbackups/weekly/ and see if you happen to have a full copy in there.  I've personally never had anything but frustration come from trying to use WHM's backup feature.  It's really just an un-tarred pkgacct file.  You can do some really simple mysql backups with mysqldump and cron.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u db_user -pdb_user_pass db_name > /full/path/to/dumpfile.sql
```

Where 'db_user' is the database username, 'db_user_pass' is that database user's password, 'db_name' is the name of the database to be dumped, and '/full/path/to/dumpfile.sql' is the location that you'd like the database to be dumped to.

You can also create a .my.cnf (note leading . is needed) in your /home/username directory containing the following:

```
[client]
user = DBUSERNAME
password = DBPASSWORD
host = localhost

[mysql]
database = DBNAME
```

(Where DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME refer to Database username, password, and database name.)

Adding this as your cron job:

```
mysqldump > /full/path/to/dumpfile.sql
```

You can set up cron jobs through cPanel->'Cron Jobs'

Comment: No, I just have it set to save daily.  The problem with this is that I am saving to a 20GB NAS and my database is around 1.5GB, so this would fill up quickly without the feature that WHM has to only save what has changed.

Comment: Ick, if that's the case I would hit up cPanel support and tell them to fix their shi**y backup system, but since that never works, I would do a couple of tests.  Since you don't have anything now, it seems like you can play with the settings a bit.. I would delete the ../daily folder and run the backup manually /scripts/cpbackup then make some changes and run it again.  After you do that check in /usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log (maybe others) and see if anything sticks out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was just testing one of my backup after so long.  Guess what, the "Account Restore" backup only created the database, but not the tables/data inside it.

I should try your mysqldump.

Thanks